# Binomial Distribution and Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $ Y_{1},Y_{2},... $ be independent random variables with the common distribution function G(y) = Pr[$ Y_{k} \le y $ ]. And let $ U_{1},...U_{n} $ be independent and uniformly distributed random variables on (0,t].

Then $ Pr[ \sum_{k=1}^{n}1(U_{k}+Y_{k} \ge t) =m] $ is recognized as the binomial distribution in which $ p = Pr[ U_{k}+Y_{k} \ge t ] = \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t}Pr[Y_{k} \ge t-u]du  $

I don't understand how the probability of the sum of the indicators results in the binomial distribution with probability of event success p. Any clarification would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum $Z_1+\cdots+Z_n$ of every i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables $(Z_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ is binomial Bin$(n,p)$ with $p=\mathbb P(Z_k=1)$. (That $Z_k$ is Bernoulli simply means that $\mathbb P(Z_k=1)+\mathbb P(Z_k=0)=1$.)

Here $Z_k=\mathbf 1_{U_k+Y_k\geqslant t}$ hence $p=\mathbb P(U_k+Y_k\geqslant t)$.

**Edit:** To compute $p=\mathbb P(U+Y\geqslant t)$, note that $\mathbb P(U+Y\geqslant t\mid U=u)=\mathbb P(u+Y\geqslant t)$ thanks to the independence of $U$ and $Y$, hence 
$$
p=\int_0^t\mathbb P(U+Y\geqslant t\mid U=u)\frac{\mathrm du}t=\int_0^t\mathbb P(Y\geqslant t-u)\frac{\mathrm du}t.
$$

Comment: Where is the Poisson process mentioned in the title?

Comment: Right this is the sum of Bernoulli random variables viewpoint of the binomial distribution. In addition, how do I move from Pr[$ U_{k} + Y_{k} \ge t $ to the integral? I can see it's kind of averaging over t, but how can I formally show it's equal? Thanks for all the help so far. Also I wasn't very sure how to label this, so I included the more general context in which this appeared (Poisson processes) as well.

Comment: If *the more general context in which this appeared* is the one of Poisson processes, it isa pity to omit it in the question. // About the computation of $p$, see Edit.